# Apache Karaf (4.2.6) shell: Unable to install webconsole

Tags: java, maven, installation, apache-karaf

I'm trying to do a feature:install webconsole in Karaf, version 4.2.6, but on every machine I try setting Karaf up on, I get this error message:

```
Error executing command: Error:
        Error downloading mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6
```

Weather its Windows or Linux Mint, I'm not able to install webconsole. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Java 1.8.0_241 and Maven 3.6.3 and set their respective environment variables on both operating systems.

Am I missing something?

Here is a full console log:

```
org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException: Error:
        Error downloading mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.<init>(MavenDownloadManager.java:91)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:457)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:224)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:393)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1062)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Error downloading mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:77)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
                ... 3 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.karaf.webconsole:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance:jar:4.2.6: [Could not transfer artifact org.apache.karaf.webconsole:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance:jar:4.2.6 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Failed to transfer file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance-4.2.6.jar with status code 501]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.configureIOException(AetherBasedResolver.java:803)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:774)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:657)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:565)
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:52)
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60)
                ... 7 more
                Suppressed: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.karaf.webconsole:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance:jar:4.2.6 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Failed to transfer file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance-4.2.6.jar with status code 501
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:489)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
                        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767)
                        ... 12 more
                Caused by: shaded.org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance-4.2.6.jar with status code 501
                        at shaded.org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1139)
                        at shaded.org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1072)
                        at shaded.org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:126)
                        at shaded.org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
                        at shaded.org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:567)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:435)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:412)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:363)
                        ... 21 more
        Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.karaf.webconsole:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance:jar:4.2.6
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767)
                ... 12 more
Error executing command: Error:
        Error downloading mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.2.6
```

Comment: I would like to add that the webconsole module installs fine in Karaf 4.2.7. For some reason it doesn't work in version 4.2.6. Thats the version I have to work in. My colleagues are able to set up Karaf 4.2.6 and install webconsole on their machines without error.

I feel like i'm missing something but what could it possibly be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories` property in `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` configuration file in order to use https instead of http. 
Since January 15th, 2020 http is disabled on Maven central

Comment: Great answer thanks.